# In rails, Turbo just appends the response from the server at the end of current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails, turbo-frames

The problem: Turbo just appends the response from server to the end of current page. Not replacing the page like expected.

Recently upgraded from Rails 6 to 7.
Also I switched from importmap to esbuild.

I have a form that is making a post to a create method. The controller responds with

```
  if @stamp.save       
        redirect_to stamps_path, notice: "Input saved"
      else
```

The strange thing that happens is that the response is being appended to the bottom of the source code from the top. So at the end of the original source code a new head-section from the response is appended like

```
<...> The whole initial html <...>
</body>
<title>Page title</title> <-- The server response gets appended after </body>
<meta .... the whole page gets repeated again
```

Not really sure what to show you here, been digging through all settings etc. I have never seen Turbo behave like this with a respons.

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.2"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.2", ">= 7.0.2.4"
gem "sprockets-rails"
gem "puma", "~> 5.6"
gem "haml-rails", "~> 2.0"
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"
gem 'devise', '~> 4.8'
gem 'devise-i18n', '~> 1.10'
gem "turbo-rails"
gem "jsbundling-rails", "~> 1.0"
gem 'sass-rails'
gem "stimulus-rails"
gem 'rubyXL', '~> 3.3'
gem "jbuilder"
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]
gem 'kaminari', '~> 1' # pagination gem
gem "bootsnap", require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  gem "web-console"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

```
{
  "private": true,
  "license": "ISC",
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "release": "npm run build && npm run publish",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.1.0",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.2.5",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.17.7"
  }
}
```

I've been trying to replicate another rails app I have using Turbo. Been looking into all settings etc. Other pages can take a redirect_to and replacing the content as expected.
I'm using haml so the HTML-structure should be fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can only think of a one way this could happen: you have `show.erb` template. Just rename it to `show.html.erb` (or *.haml*, *.slim*, it doesn't matter).

---

By default, the forms are submitted as *TURBO_STREAM*, it's what *rails* shows in the logs, however, this is not the whole picture. The form submit request [sets](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/blob/v7.2.5/src/core/drive/form_submission.ts#L161) `Accept` header:

```rb
Accept: text/vnd.turbo-stream.html, text/html, application/xhtml+xml
#       ^
# here is where `TURBO_STREAM` comes from
```

These are the response `Content-Type`s that *turbo* expects to receive. When you use `respond_to` block in controller actions, `Accept` header is what determines which `format` block to call:

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  if @model.save(model_params)
    # if you have turbo_stream, it will run first
    # format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace(model) }
    # if you don't have turbo_stream, next format in `Accept` header is html
    format.html { redirect_to model_url(@model) }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @model }
    # if nothing matches, you get `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error.
    # the one you get when trying to render `format.js`, but Turbo 
    # doesn't handle js format, so it doesn't send `Accept: text/javascript`
  else
    format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.json { render json: @model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

When you use `respond_to` block, *rails* will automatically set some render options, one of which is `:content_type` which in turn sets `Content-Type` response header. So if `format.html` block runs it sets `Content-Type: text/html` which *turbo* knows how to handle by redirecting or replacing the page content.

The important part is that we went from *turbo_stream* format to *html*. Needless to say that *html* needs to render html looking response and *turbo_stream* has to be a `<turbo-stream>` tag.

What happens when you don't use `respond_to` block. *Rails* will try to render a template that matches the format. For example, *turbo_stream* request will look for `show.turbo_stream.erb` then `show.html.erb` then `show.erb`, like this:

```rb
render :show, formats: [:turbo_stream, :html]
```

Let's say it finds `show.html.erb`, because there is an `html` extension present, *rails* will set response *Content-Type* to `text/html` and everything works as expected.

However, if it finds `show.erb`, there is nothing to tell *rails* that it is in *html* format, we didn't use `respond_to` block so response *Content-Type* is not set explicitly, the only option left is to fallback to the first *Accept* type, which is *turbo_stream*. Now you're rendering an *html* template but response type is *turbo_stream*, and there is no `<turbo-stream>` tag.

When *turbo* sees a *turbo_stream* response it [appends](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/blob/v7.2.5/src/core/streams/stream_message_renderer.ts#L9) it to the document, which is what you're seeing. Since there are no *<turbo-stream>* instructions, it just stays untouched.

---

Long story short, something along the way needs to set the correct content type.

Either use `respond_to` block which will set necessary render options. Or set render options yourself: `content_type: "text/html"`. Or let *rails* know the content type by using `html.erb` and `turbo_stream.erb` extensions.

Note, when you redirect, *turbo_stream* content type stays, because *turbo* handles the redirect on the front end. If there is no `html.erb` extension and no `respond_to` block in the show action, you get a content type mismatch.

Comment: omg, I love you.. This was THE solution and the best education I could get.