# Trubo Rails appends content to outside of the body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, turbo

originally based on:
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5564

My Turbo Rails 7 app appears to respond correctly but appends content to outside of the body, leaving the rest of the body in place:

Start the server with ./bin/dev

Go to http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/sign_up

Input test username & password

[image]

Click "Sign Up"

Current behavior
[image]

here's what the Rails log says:

[image]

Notice that if you examine the HTML, the "hello world" — which is the correct response from `welcome/index.erb`, get appended outside of the closing `<body>` tag

[image]

Expected result:
• The signup form goes away and the user is correctly taken to the home page

Comment: for a few extra details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75471426/207090

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the template that is being responded with doesn't correctly have a format e.g. `.html`

to fix: rename `index.erb` to `index.html.erb`